# loadinfile issue while inserting date time into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem, i need to upload a csv file with few columns in it including date time column into database. while uploading the data by reading each row and inserting into database it is working fine with date and time. but when i use load infile the whole date and time appears in database column of the table as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 the data type is date. and i am writing the data & time in csv file in the same format `$date =  date("Y-m-d h:i:s");` using php. what might be the reason?

Comment: Can you show us the script where you add to the db?

Comment: `$loadsql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$newcsvfile.'" INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\r" IGNORE 1 LINES';
mysql_query($loadsql) or die(mysql_error());`